# Unexpected token error for react fixed-data-table

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

I'm trying to get the fixed-data-table sample to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';

// Table data as a list of array.
const rows = [
  ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
  ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
  ['a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
// .... and more
];

// Render your table
module.exports = React.createClass({
  render:  function() {
    return (
      <Table
        rowHeight={50}
        rowsCount={rows.length}
        width={200}
        height={200}
        headerHeight={50}>

      {/*if I have just this column, the page will render*/}
      <Column
        header={<Cell>Col 1</Cell>}
        cell={<Cell>Column 1 static content</Cell>}
        width={500}
        />

      {/*This column causes the error*/}
      <Column
        header={<Cell>Col 3</Cell>}
        cell={({rowIndex, ...props}) => (
        <Cell {...props}>
          Data for column 3: {rows[rowIndex][2]}
        </Cell>
        )}
        width={500}
      />
      </Table>
    );
  }
});
```

but when I run webpack it keeps throwing this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/xxxx/Sample.jsx: Unexpected token (33:24)
  31 |     <Column
  32 |       header={<Cell>Col 3</Cell>}
> 33 |       cell={({rowIndex, ...props}) => (
     |                         ^
  34 |         <Cell {...props}>
  35 |           Data for column 3: {rows[rowIndex][2]}
  36 |         </Cell>
```

I think webpack sees {rowIndex, ...props} as an incorrectly formatted object, but I'm not sure where to go next.

here's my webpack.config:

```
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'server/components'),
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090', 
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', 
        "./entry.jsx"
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/server/public/js/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/js/build/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    }
};
```

Comment: What are you using for JSX transpilation?

Comment: I got stuck on this exact same problem one time, here is another way to make fixed-data-table work: http://4dev.tech/2015/12/reactjs-datatable-with-sort-filter-and-pagination-example-part-1/

Comment: fixed-data-table has now been discontinued. This is why we released our React port - http://reactdatagrid.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the right transforms installed and enabled (for Babel 6 you need [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread)), you could be running into [bug #T2631](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2631):

> ```js
> export default ( { title, ...other } ) => {
>     // do something
> };
> ```
>
> fails with the output
>
> ```js
> SyntaxError: test-fn-spread.js: Binding rvalue (1:26)
> > 1 | export default ( { title, ...other } ) => {
>     |                           ^
>   2 |     // do something
>   3 | };
> ```

The bug [was fixed](https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/72b6e42b345ab3205cc9f0e080e64e36543d293e) in 6.1.2.

Comment: I didn't have all the right transforms.  I needed to add the "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread".  Thanks!